# Query relationship values from a collection

Tags: php, laravel, collections, eloquent, relationship

I have 3 tables, users > posts > comments. User has many posts and post has many comments. I am trying to get only comments from a user. Something like this:

```
$user->posts->comments->where(...)->get()
```

- `$user->posts` returns a collection of collection of posts
- Thus, if I try `$user->posts->first()->comments`, it returns collection of post's comments.

However, with the above scenario (`posts->comments`), it doesn't work because posts is a collection

I believe running a for loop is not the optimal way, even though I believe it can be achieved that way.

What is the Laravel way of achieving this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Has Many Through, see https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through.

In your User model:

```
public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Comment', 'App\Post');
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Cant believe i missed that